# cannon.js object is flipping end to end

Tags: javascript, three.js, physics, cannon.js

I'm working on a little [three.js scene](https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/7cb23aaee121cf0c0a253394c50cd0a1) in which I want to drive a car down a road. The trouble is my car is flipping end to end each frame, instead of rolling on its tires:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can make my car roll with cannon.js? Any pointers would be hugely helpful. For the sake of preservation, here's my raw scene:

```js
var carBody,
    floorBody,
    pressed = {},
    rotation = 0,
    clock = new THREE.Clock(),
    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(),
    container = document.querySelector('body'),
    w = container.clientWidth,
    h = container.clientHeight,
    scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, w/h, 0.1, 100000),
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, container),
    renderConfig = {antialias: true, alpha: true},
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(renderConfig);
controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0.75);
controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
camera.position.set(0,80,-4900);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(w, h);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  w = container.clientWidth;
  h = container.clientHeight;
  camera.aspect = w/h;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(w, h);
})

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  if (car && carBody && carBody.position) {
    moveCar();
    updatePhysics();
    moveCamera();
    //controls.update();
  }
}

function getPlane(img, w, h, wrap) {
  var texture = loader.load(img);
  if (wrap) {
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.repeat.set(10, 10);
  }
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  });
  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(w, h, 10, 10);
  return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}

function getSides() {
  var d = 300;
  var group = new THREE.Group();
  for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
    var plane = getPlane('asphalt.jpg', 10000, 200, true);
    plane.position.y = 100;
    plane.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, -Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2);
    plane.position.x = i == 0 ? -d : d;
    group.add(plane);
  }
  return group;
}

function getSky() {
  var directions  = ['right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom', 'front', 'back'];
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50000, 50000, 50000);
  var materialArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i<6; i++)
    materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: loader.load(directions[i] + '.bmp'),
      side: THREE.BackSide
    }));
  return new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialArray );
}

function getCar() {
  var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.load('car.mtl', function(mat) {
    mat.preload();
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(mat);
    objLoader.load('car.obj', function(obj) {
      window.car = obj;
      car.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
      obj.position.set(0, 0, -4800);
      scene.add(obj);
    })
  })
}

function getPhysics() {
  world = new CANNON.World();
  world.gravity.set(0, -100, 0); // earth = -9.82 m/s
  world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase();
  world.broadphase.useBoundingBoxes = true;
  var solver = new CANNON.GSSolver();
  solver.iterations = 7;
  solver.tolerance = 0.1;
  world.solver = solver;
  world.quatNormalizeSkip = 0;
  world.quatNormalizeFast = false;
  world.defaultContactMaterial.contactEquationStiffness = 1e9;
  world.defaultContactMaterial.contactEquationRelaxation = 4;
  return world;
}

function addPhysics() {
  var m = getPhysicsMaterial();
  carBody = new CANNON.Body({
    mass: 10,
    material: m,
    shape: new CANNON.Sphere(30),
    linearDamping: 0.6,
    angularDamping: 0.8,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 30, -4900)
  });
  world.addBody(carBody);
  // floor
  var q = floor.quaternion;
  var floorBody = new CANNON.Body({
    mass: 0, // mass = 0 makes the body static
    material: m,
    shape: new CANNON.Plane(),
    quaternion: new CANNON.Quaternion(-q._x, q._y, q._z, q._w)
  });
  world.addBody(floorBody);
}

function getPhysicsMaterial() {
  var m = new CANNON.Material('slipperyMaterial');
  var c = new CANNON.ContactMaterial(m, m, {
    friction: 0.3,
    restitution: 0.3,
  })
  world.addContactMaterial(c);
  return m;
}

function moveCar() {
  var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds
  var moveDistance = 2000 * delta; // n pixels per second
  // set roll sensitivity
  var sensitivity = 1.5;
  var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta * sensitivity;
  // determine the direction to travel
  var p = carBody.position;
  var dir = new THREE.Vector3(p.x, p.y, p.z);
  dir.sub(camera.position).normalize(); // vector b/w camera and car
  if (pressed['W'] || pressed['ARROWUP']) {
    carBody.velocity.x += moveDistance * dir.x;
    carBody.velocity.z += moveDistance * dir.z;
  }
  if (pressed['S'] || pressed['ARROWDOWN']) {
    carBody.velocity.x -= moveDistance * dir.x;
    carBody.velocity.z -= moveDistance * dir.z;
  }
  if (pressed['A'] || pressed['ARROWLEFT']) {
    rotation += rotateAngle;
  }
  if (pressed['D'] || pressed['ARROWRIGHT']) {
    rotation -= rotateAngle;
  }
  if (pressed[' ']) {
    carBody.velocity.y = 10;
  }
}

function updatePhysics() {
  world.step(1/60);
  car.position.copy(carBody.position);
  car.quaternion.copy(carBody.quaternion);
}

function moveCamera() {
  var rotZ = Math.cos(rotation);
  var rotX = Math.sin(rotation);
  var distance = 100;
  camera.position.x = carBody.position.x - (distance * rotX);
  camera.position.y = carBody.position.y + 20;
  camera.position.z = carBody.position.z - (distance * rotZ);
  camera.lookAt(car.position);
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  pressed[e.key.toUpperCase()] = true;
})
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  pressed[e.key.toUpperCase()] = false;
})

/**
* Add elems
**/

var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
scene.add(light);

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(floor);

var street = getPlane('asphalt.jpg', 10000, 1000, true);
street.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
street.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
scene.add(street);

var sides = getSides();
scene.add(sides);

var sky = getSky();
scene.add(sky);

var car = getCar();

var world = getPhysics();
addPhysics();
render();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #aaa;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cannon.js/0.6.2/cannon.js'></script>
<script src='https://raw.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/ObjLoader.js'></script>
<script src='https://raw.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js'></script>
<script src='https://raw.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js'></script>
```

Comment: It appears one must mock up each tire as a object in the physics world: http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/demos/rigidVehicle.html

Comment: Put all the components of the car in a [`Group`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group) and set the rotation attribute of the group object.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I believe that's actually what I've done--in the scene above `car` is a `group`, and the rotation is being applied to that group, which rolls it around end over end, as if the group were inside a sphere that's rolling.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood. The rotation of the group defines the orientation of the entire car. If you want to roll the wheels, then you have to change the rotation attributes of the wheel objects (which are sub objects of the group).

Comment: Yes, exactly! I think to model them as "rigid bodies" I have to cast some cannon.js spells on them too. Am consulting the spellbook now...